# how to merge same value dict of list

Tags: python

Here is my list of dictionary.

```
a = [{'ID': 1, 'FID': 938119, 'LEFT': 'A', 'LTIME': '1:10', 'RIGHT': '', 'RTIME': ''},
     {'ID': 2, 'FID': 938119, 'LEFT': 'B', 'LTIME': '1:55', 'RIGHT': '', 'RTIME': ''},
     {'ID': 3, 'FID': 938119, 'LEFT': '', 'LTIME': '', 'RIGHT': 'A', 'RTIME': '1:20'},
     {'ID': 4, 'FID': 938119, 'LEFT': 'A', 'LTIME': '1:56', 'RIGHT': '', 'RTIME': ''},
     {'ID': 5, 'FID': 938120, 'LEFT': 'A', 'LTIME': '1:36', 'RIGHT': '', 'RTIME': ''},
     ]
```

How can I get output like below:(Group by FID and LEFT, sum LTIME and RTIME)

```
b = [
    {'ID': 1, 'FID': 938119, 'LEFT': 'A', 'LTIME': '3:06', 'RIGHT': 'A', 'RTIME': '1:20'},
    {'ID': 2, 'FID': 938119, 'LEFT': 'B', 'LTIME': '1:55', 'RIGHT': '', 'RTIME': ''},
    {'ID': 3, 'FID': 938120, 'LEFT': 'A', 'LTIME': '1:36', 'RIGHT': '', 'RTIME': ''},
]
```

Comment: You are providing input and output which is good but I can't tell how they are related.  What is zone and cycle?  Why is record 4 and 5 missing but record 3 now has the FID value of record 5?  RTIME of record 3 is now part of record 1? etc

Comment: sorry ,I write it wrongly, its 3:06